# How to express a "simple past" idea that could happen in the future?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Ok, Let's see this conversation.

Tom & Mary are working in a shop right now. It is 4 pm *NOW*. Normally the working hour will finish at 5 pm.

**Tom:** *There is not too much work today. Can I leave at 4.35?*

**Mary:** *You can leave at 4.45 because if you leave before 4.45, the boss will ask you, "Why did you leave so early?"*

Now my question is that how can we change the sentence if we omit the double quotation mark?

If I write the sentence like this (*You can leave at 4.45 because if you leave before 4.45, the boss will ask you that why you left so early.*), then **will it break the universe**?

Comment: Just remove "that". *You can leave at 4.45 because if you leave before 4.45, the boss will ask you why you left so early.*

Comment: Just by the by, because *ask* takes interrogative clauses you need a clause beginning with a *wh-* word, you can't use *that* here ...

Comment: +1 Nice question! [Just by the by, because *ask* takes interrogative clauses you need a clause beginning with a *wh-* word, you can't use *that* here ...]

Comment: @Mamta, if I say "*You can leave at 4.45 because if you leave before 4.45, the boss will ask you why you left so early.*", then will it break the universe because the "leaving" action has not happened yet?

Comment: No @Tom it will not because "the boss will ask" is a future statement, not a present or past one. But since by that time, Tom would have left, the boss will on the next occasion of meeting him bring up the question and ask him why he left early.

Comment: @Mamta, what if I change "*you*" to "*me*"  as in "*You can leave at 4.45 because if you leave before 4.45, the boss will ask me why you left so early.*". If this case the boss will ask Mary that "*Why did Tom leave early?*"

Comment: @Tom, in that case, the sentence can be written as: *You can leave at 4.45 because if you leave before 4.45, the boss will ask me why did you leave so early.*

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the boss will ask that at some later time, when he/she finds out. In that case: "If you leave before 4:35, the boss will ask why you left so early".
We do not normally tense-shift this into "the boss will ask why you will have left so early".

If the boss would see Tom leaving and ask right in that moment, then the sentence should be: "If you leave before 4:35, the boss will ask why you are leaving so early".

---

I'll note the original direct-speech sentence in your question is broken in two ways. Mary should have said: *You can leave at 4.45 because if you leave before 4.35, the boss will ask you "why did you leave so early".*

When you ask someone "*that* XYZ", you're making a request, not a question. In a similar vein, you can say "my question is how we can…" or "my question is: how can we…", but not "my question is *that* how can we…"

Comment: I agree with the first part of this answer (+1),  "If you leave before 4:35, the boss will ask why you left so early".

Comment: My note about brokenness refers to the original, pre-edit version of the question.